# Is my graphics card broken?

Tags: linux, graphics-card

I tried to run my puppy linux, and the loading screens were okay, but the actual desktop was all blurry, and had the wrong colors. Mainly pink and neon green. After a few seconds it restarted. Same graphics on second try, but now the desktop loaded. I was able to see the cursor moving when I moved the mouse, but the cursor was huge and rectangular.

I have removed my graphics card, and now use the integrated one. Everything seems to be working fine.

**Edit**: Windows behavior

Grapics card **in**: I try to load chrome, open a new tab in firefox, or start a movie, I get an error message:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error
>
> > R6034

Graphics card **out**: no error.

How can I make sure this is worth a trip to the shop?

Comment: What make/model is your video card?  Where you using the manufacturer's driver or just the Linux base one?

Comment: VTX3D VX6450, with base linux driver

Comment: @András Did you recently update drivers?

Comment: @András that's nVidia, yes?  Check online for nVidia drivers for Linux.

Comment: This is an AMD card, and have not updated drivers, neither in Windows, nor in Linux.